# How to start my service file after network is configured?

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, networkmanager, systemd-networkd

I want my service to only start when network is completely configured (ip address, interfaces, etc.), and restart my service whenever network restarts(because configuration may change). To achieve this I thought I'll need to add `After=network.target` and `Wants=network.target` to my service file. So that whenever network is restarted my service also restarts and only starts after network is completely up.

In my centos 7 VM when I restart network with command `/etc/init.d/network restart` I notice that there's no change in network.target, it's still up and not restarting, I tried installing NetworkManager and restart with it, but I didn't see any change. I noticed network.service restarted. Should we be using network.service instead of network.target? In all the online resources it is given how to use network.target or network-pre.target, network-online.target, etc.

In my Ubuntu 18.04 VM, I tried restarting network with command `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, but it says file itself is not present, maybe something is wrong with my VM? Here also I tried by installing Network-Manager, but there seems to be no change in network.target status. Here I also noticed that there's no network.service file. Here we are using neplan config file, but when I restart using network-manager, there's no change.

How to write my service file? Or service file is correct but I'm not properly restarting network? Should service file be different for rpm based distros and deb?

Comment: Try adding in your custom **systemd service**: `PartOf=network.target` or `PartOf=network.service` (I think it should be the second one)

Comment: Usually in some systems `network.service` is an alias to `NetworkManager.service` so maybe you want to use `NetworkManager` instead.

Comment: Hi @EdgarMagallon, configuration is not getting updated when I use NetworkManager restart, and also everyone doesn't have NetworkManager in their systems, therefore I wanted to use network.target which is present in most linux systems to check if network is up. Even network.service is not found in Ubuntu, also for some reason I don't know how to restart network in Ubuntu, maybe there's some netplan command. In which cases (apart from system reboot) will network.target restart? Because even in centos it's not restarting when we restart network.

Comment: Using `network.target` should be refused so you will not be able to (re)start manually (but if you stop manually and your custom systemd service has: `PartOf=network.target` then it should stop the unit). However I guess you should use: `network-online.target` instead of `network.target`. From [this page:](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/) *"network-online.target is a target that actively waits until the nework is "up", where the definition of "up" is defined by the network management software."*

Comment: Check if all of you have `network-online.target` and if you do, then use `PartOf=network-online.service` in your service. Btw, about `Centos` are you using `systemd`? Because I see you are using `/etc/init.d/network restart` which is part of the `init` daemon but maybe that's irrelevant because some systems redirect `init` script to systemd scripts (AFAIK, I noticed this behavior in `Parrot Os`)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, thanks for the reply, yes, the other targets are also there, but they are not responding when I restart network in my CentOS VM. They're just staying up.

Comment: Can you provide what you have in `/etc/init.d/network`. Also provide (in your question) the output when you run `/etc/init.d/network restart`. I'm thinking your CentOS does.not really use systemd.